# Semi-Inner Product question

Tags: analysis

I have a semi-inner product space question, that is to prove that $u(0,y)=0$ from this property $u(ax+by,z)=au(x,z)+bu(y,z)$ and we assume that $a=0$. Also, note that $x,y,$ and $z$ are vectors and $a,b$ is a real number field since $a=0$. This is an exercise from Conway functional analysis textbook. I don't understand Conway's explanation, if someone can explain it to me in simple terms and break it down, I would totally appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $\vec{x}$ any fixed vector. Then $0\cdot \vec{x}=\vec{0}.$ Now,using the linearity property you have

$$u(\vec{0},y)=u(0\cdot \vec{x}+0\cdot \vec{x},\vec{y})=0u(\vec{x},\vec{y})+0u(\vec{x},\vec{y})=0+0=0.$$

You can start showing that $u(ax,y)=au(x,y)$ just considering $b=0.$ In such a case

$$u(\vec{0},y)=u(0\cdot \vec{x},\vec{y})=0u(\vec{x},\vec{y})=0.$$